# What is {what} supposed to mean in the official documentation?

Tags: vimscript, variables

I keep seeing mention of `{what}` here and there, mainly in `eval.txt`, `popup.txt`, `terminal.txt`, `syntax.txt`, and `channel.txt`.

From `:h popup_create()`

```
popup_create({what}, {options})

Open a popup window showing {what}, which is either:
                - a buffer number
                - a string
                - a list of strings
                - a list of text lines with text properties
                When {what} is not a buffer number, a buffer is created with
                'buftype' set to "popup".  That buffer will be wiped out once
                the popup closes.
```

I'm unsure on the meaning of `{what}`, though I did think it was supposed to be replaced with whatever was mentioned about it in the documentation.

I tried running `popup_create({what}, {options})`, and it always shows

```
E121: Undefined variable: what
```

What does `{what}` actually do generally speaking? Is it just a placeholder or something useful in and of itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `:h notation`:

> Curly braces denote parts of the command which must appear,
> but which can take a number of different values.

So, a placeholder.

Comment: Nice, guess I'll read `notation.txt` first next time :D